# Page navigation parameters with complex data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I navigate from a page to another. I know how to Transfer some data between These pages:

"Calling Page":

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/ViewerPage.xaml?image=" + mImageID, UriKind.Relative));
```

"Called Page":

```
 NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("image", out mImageURL)
```

But how can I Transfer more complex data?

```
 List<tring> mList = new List<string>;
 mList.Add("test-1");
 mList.Add("test-2");
```

I want to transfer now the complete list `mList' to the called page.
Any indeas how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first page do the following:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["param"] = mList;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PhonePageOne.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And in the second retrieve the parameter:

```
List<string> p = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["param"] as List<string>;
```

The PhoneApplicationService.State dictionary is a temporary storage location which persists until your app is deactivated.

Other option could be to declare a static member in, for example, App.xaml.cs and use it to save thoe object from one page an to retreive from the second one.